# How to move (pan) a bezier path?

Tags: ios, core-graphics, uigesturerecognizer, quartz-2d, uibezierpath

I am using quartz-2d and drawing lines using `UIBezierPath`. I want to pan these lines according to user interaction. One way is to define a `UIView` and draw on that view and add `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to it.

But the problem is that there are extenders at both ends of the line, so using those extenders user can change the size and orientation of line. And with `UIView` approach it is quite difficult to keep changing size of view when orientation changes.

So is there any way to interact with bezier path without using `UIView`? Is it possible to detect touch events on bezier path?

Comment: the `UIBezierPath` is not inherited from `UIResponder` class, which defines the short answer: no. you can catch touch events in any class which inherited (directly/indirectly) from `UIResponder` class only.

Comment: @holex: Got it. So is there any other way around to solve my problem?

Comment: yes, the obvious solution is to draw your Bezier curve into a `UIView` class, and implement a custom touch detection according to how your current curve flows.

Comment: @blancos is there above solved? if yes, then please give me idea or suggestion for the same and your help will be appreciate for me.

Comment: @NikunjJadav : no other way to do it other than using UIView. Reason is mentioned in first comment of holex. Manipulation of UIView is a pain, but it can be done.